# How to see objects from photos in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

For example, I am looking at some place in Christchurch, New Zeland,

Below I found some photo gallery. I found some modern multilevel building and the bridge. Unfortunetely if I double click on image and go to associated location, I see only village huts around.

Proof:

[image]

Location: https://goo.gl/maps/V3Fd0

**UPDATE**

Examples of "incorrect" views:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photos in Google Maps are not always tagged with the exact location. I can't even double-click the photo to get to a location.

When you search for "Worcester Boulevard Bridge, Christchurch" you come to a street and if you follow it to the water you come to this location: https://goo.gl/maps/BCt9X

This is the location of the photo (although the building is under repair and changed significantly). In the upper left you can even choose "Street View - Dec 2007" and you see the building like it was in the photo.

[image: screen shot from Google Maps]

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that this town is rapidly changing now. This is why I not found many buildings. This building looks other way for me: with some crane and partially changed. Also one church I found was partially destroyed. This made an illusion maps not work correctly.